# How can I derive the second degree equation for a curve if I know the slope at two points and the y-intercept = 0?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, interpolation

How can I derive the second degree equation for a curve if I know the slope at two points and the x and y-intercepts = 0?

Answer (score 2):

Say that the equation is $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ which makes $$f'(x)=2ax+b$$ So, now consider three points $(
x_1,x_2,x_3)$. You then have $$f'(x_1)=2ax_1+b$$ $$f'(x_2)=2ax_2+b$$ $$f(x_3)=ax_3^2+bx_3+c$$ and you know the value of each lhs.

I am sure that you can take it from here.